Why does a SignalR connection not exist after starting the client?
I have a couple of clients that intermittently get the following exception:

Connection 'xxx' does not exist.
System.IO.IOException: Connection 'xxx' does not exist.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.DefaultHubLifetimeManager`1.InvokeConnectionAsync[T](String connectionId, String methodName, Object[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

This might even happen a few seconds after the client called StartAsync on the hub.
The above exception is thrown server-side when the server tries to invoke a method on the client. So I increased the logging to Debug
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections": "Debug",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "Debug",

The client builfds the connection as follows:
hub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl(Constants.HubsUrl + "/MainHub", options =>
{
    options.Headers.Add(Constants.HeaderToken, token);
    options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
})
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddDebug();
    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Warning);
})
.WithAutomaticReconnect(new[] { 
    TimeSpan.Zero, 
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
})
.Build();

What could be the reason for such an exception and is there a way to actually known when and why this happens, and above all, how to fix the problem?

Do you mean this error only happened when the application just started or just the client side started? How you build the connection at the client?
